# .htaccess Rewrite directory/file to new directory/file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite a directory and filename at the same time using .htaccess, but for some reason I can't find anything about such a case on the net. Tried googling what not, but there is simply not an example for this.

When I access a php file in the following directory:

website.com/somedir/somefile.php

I want to open a file that is contained at:

website.com/dirone/dirtwo/dirthree/dirfour/anotherfile.php

Tried simply 301 redirecting the directory

website.com/somedir/

to

website.com/dirone/dirtwo/dirthree/dirfour/

with

```
Redirect 301 http://website.com/somedir/ http://website.com/dirone/dirtwo/dirthree/dirfour/
```

But that would only work if the file name was the same. However in my case the filename changes from somefile.php to anotherfile.php as well.

Also tried something like:

```
RewriteRule ^somedir/somefile\.php website.com/dirone/dirtwo/dirthree/dirfour/anotherfile.php [L,QSA,NC]
```

But it did not work.

Any help would gladly be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you remove website.com: `RewriteRule ^somedir/somefile\.php dirone/dirtwo/dirthree/dirfour/anotherfile.php [L,QSA,NC]`

Comment: Redirect /somedir/somefile.php http://website.com/dirone/dirtwo/dirthree/dirfour/anotherfile.php  If same domain then you don't need to add it either, but original url should not include the domain and you need to specify files names.

Comment: @DusanBajic Tried that as well, didn't work.

smozgur I tried without using the website.com too, didn't work as well.

Comment: @gvmk my comment hides http:// at the beginning of the second part above. Just make sure you put http:// before website.com, because it is how it is supposed to work and of course I tested what I pasted above which worked successfully. And I know it might sound silly but reopen your browser after making change in the htaccess, don't test it in the same failed window. Redirect /folder/file.php http:// domain.com/folder/other file.com I put space after http:// to make it appear.